# Trying to access pointer after resetting

Tags: c++, pointers

Debugging an application and experimenting a bit I came to a quite strange behaviour that can be reproduced with a following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> p(new int);

    *p = 10;
    int& ref = *p;    
    int* direct_p = &(*p);

    p.reset();

    std::cout << *p << "\n";        // a) SIGSEGV
    std::cout << ref << "\n";       // b) 0
    std::cout << *direct_p << "\n"; // c) 0
    return 0;
}
```

As I see it, all three variants have to cause undefined behaviour. Keeping that in the mind, I have these questions:

1. Why do `ref` and `direct_p` nevertheless point to zero? (not 10) (I mean, the mechanism of `int`'s destruction seems strange to me, what's the point for compiler to rewrite on unused memory?)
2. Why don't b) and c) fire SIGSEGV?
3. Why does behaviour of a) differ from b) and c)?

Comment: You said it yourself, it is undefined behavior, anything could happen and it doesn't make much sense to figure out why.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. It really is that simple.

Comment: Undefined behavior means ANYTHING can happen, and it did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p.reset();` is the equivalent of `p.reset(nullptr);`. So the unique_ptr's internal pointer is being set to null. Consequently doing `*p` ends up with the same result as trying to dereference a raw pointer that's null.

On the other hand, `ref` and `direct_p` are still left pointing at the memory formerly occupied by that int. Trying to use them to read that memory gets into Undefined Behavior territory, so in principle we can't conclude anything...

But in practice, there are a few things we can make educated assumptions and guesses about.

Since that memory location was valid shortly before, it's most likely still present (hasn't been unmapped from the address space, or other such implementation-specific things) when your program accesses it through `ref` and `direct_p`. C++ doesn't demand that the memory should become completely inaccessible. So in this case you simply end up "successfully" reading whatever happens to be at that memory location at that point during the program's execution.

As for why the value happens to be 0, well there are a couple possibilities. One is that you could be running in a debug mode which purposefully zeroes out deallocated memory. Another possibility is that by the time you access that memory through `ref` and `direct_p` something else has already re-used it for a different purpose which ended up leaving it with that value. Your `std::cout << *p << "\n";` line could potentially have done that.

Answer (score 1):

Undefined behaviour does not mean that code must trigger an abnormal termination.   It means that anything can happen.   Abnormal termination is only one possible result.    Inconsistency of behaviour between different instances of undefined behaviour is another.   Another possible (albeit rare in practice) is appearing to "work correctly" (however one defines "work correctly") until the next full moon, and then mysteriously behaving differently.

From a perspective of increasing average programmer skill and increasing software quality, electrocuting the programmer whenever they write code with undefined behaviour might be considered desirable.

Comment: dont forget the dragons coming alive after UB

Comment: That only happens if specific hardware, firmware, software, and wetware combinations are present, Creris.

Answer (score 1):

> Why nevertheless ref and direct_p point to zero? (not 10) (I mean, the
>   mechanism of int's destruction seems strange to me, what's the point
>   for compiler to rewrite on unused memory?)

It's not the compiler, it's C++/C libraries that changes memory. In your particular case, libc does something funny, as it reallocates heap data, when the value is freed:

```
Hardware watchpoint 3: *direct_p
_int_free (have_lock=0, p=0x614c10, av=0x7ffff7535b20 <main_arena>) at malloc.c:3925
3925        while ((old = catomic_compare_and_exchange_val_rel (fb, p, old2)) != old2);
```

> Why b) and c) don't fire SIGSEGV?

`SIGSEGV` is triggered by the kernel if an attempt to access memory outside of allocated address space is made. Normally, libc won't actually remove the pages after deallocating memory - it would be too expensive. You are writing to an address that is unmapped by libc - but kernel doesn't know about that. You can use a memory barrier library (e.g. ElectricFence, great for debugging) to have that happen.

> Why behavior of a) differs from b) and c)?

You made value of `p` point to some memory, say 100. You then effectively created aliases for that memory location, so `direct_p` and `ref` will point to 100. Note, that they aren't variable references, they are memory references. So changes you make to `p` have no effect on them. You then deallocated `p`, it's value becomes `0` (i.e. it now points to a memory address `0`). Attempting to read a value from memory address `0` guarantees a `SIGSEGV`. Reading values from memory address `100` is bad idea, but is not fatal (as explained above).

Answer (score 1):

As others have said *undefined behavior* means quite literally anything can happen. The code is unpredictable. But let me try to shed some light on question 'b' with an example.

`SIGSEGV` is attributed to a hardware fault reported by hardware with an MMU (Memory management unit). Your level of memory protection and therefore your level of SIGSEGV thrown can depend greatly on the MMU your hardware is using (*[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)*). If your un-allocated pointer happens to point to an ok address you will be able to read the memory their, if it points somewhere bad then your MMU will freak out and raise a SIGSEGV with your program.

Take for example though the MPC5200. This processor is quite old and has a somewhat rudimentary MMU. It can be quite difficult to get it to crash causing a segfault.

For example the following will not necessarily cause a SIGSEGV on the MPC5200:

```
int *p = NULL;
*p;
*p = 1;
printf("%d", *p); // This actually prints 1 which is insane
```

The only way i could get this to throw a segfault was with the following code:

```
int *p = NULL;
while (true) {
  *(--p) = 1;
}
```

To wrap up, undefined behavior really does mean undefined.